# Split An Erlang List, X, into a List of All X's Sublists

Tags: list, erlang, sublist

`lists:sublist/2` and `lists:sublist/3` make it simple to extract a single sublist from a list, but is there a BiF or module that returns a list of all of a list's sublists?

i.e.

```
lists:awesome_sublist_function([1,2,3,4]) ->
  [[1], [2], [3], [4], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], 
  [2,3], [2,4], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4], [2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
```

Can build my own, but wondered if the problem has been solved before anywhere?

Comment: No, but it should be easy enough to write.  Looks like a job for lists:unfold/4 - unfortunately it doesn't exist yet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your test case is forgetting [1,3,4], but it could look something like this:

```
-module(settheory).
-export([combinations/1]).

combinations([]) ->
    [];
combinations([H | T]) ->
    CT = combinations(T),
    [[H]] ++ [[H | L] || L <- CT] ++ CT.

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
combinations_test() ->
    ?assertEqual(
       combinations([1,2,3,4]),
       lists:sort([[1], [2], [3], [4], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4],
                   [2,3], [2,4], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4],
                   [2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]])),
    ok.
```

Comment: Certainly does the job, thanks! (and yes, I missed [1,3,4] - now added to the question).  I'm going to go away and think about a tail recursive version.

Comment: Apart from the fun of doing it I wouldn't spend too much time doing this, The difference in efficiency probably won't be very much.

Comment: You're right.  Speed-wise, doesn't make much of a difference, even on large lists.  Not much difference to the stack either - I wonder if that's because the result is only going to be appended anyway.  On a list of 24 items, repeated a hundred times, a tail call version had a smaller median and a tighter range, but no real difference to the mean. (It was fun though :) ).

Comment: In eunit assert macros, you should add the expected value as the first parameter to the assert macro, the value you're testing is the last parameter. This makes for nicer output messages.