# Parallel power set generation in Erlang?

Tags: recursion, erlang, parallel-processing, pseudocode, powerset

There is a lot of example [implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set) of generating a powerset of a set in Java, Python and others, but I still can not understand how the actual algorithm works.

**What are the steps taken by an algorithm to generate a power set P(S) of a set S?**

(For example, the power set of {1,2,3,4} is {{}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}, {3}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}, {4}, {1,4}, {2,4}, {1,2,4}, {3,4}, {1,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}}.)

UPD: I have found [this](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~amk/foo/csci356/notes/ch1/solutions/recursionSol.html) explanation, but still I don't get it. I am trying to understand the algorithm of generating a power set, because I would like to write a parallel implementation of it - the following sequential Erlang implementation has an enormous stack and can not count more than 30-elements set on a machine with 8 GB RAM:

```
powerset(Lst) ->
    N = length(Lst),
    Max = trunc(math:pow(2,N)),
    [[lists:nth(Pos+1,Lst) || Pos <- lists:seq(0,N-1), I band (1 bsl Pos) =/= 0] || I <- lists:seq(0,Max-1)].
```

**UPD2:**

This snippet returns all subsets of a set [a,b,c], except [a,b,c]:

```
generate_all_subsets([],Full_list,Result) ->
    Result;
generate_all_subsets([Element|Rest_of_list],Full_list,Result) ->
    Filtered_list = [X || X <- Full_list, X =/= Element],
    ?DBG("*Current accumulated result: ~w ~n", [Result]),
    Result2 = generate_subsets(Element,Filtered_list,[],[]),
    ?DBG("Generated new result: ~w ~n", [Result2]),
    New_result = lists:append(Result,Result2),
    ?DBG("Got new accumulated result: ~w ~n", [New_result]),
    generate_all_subsets(Rest_of_list,Full_list,New_result).



generate_subsets(Main_element,[],Accumulated_list,Result) ->
    Result;
generate_subsets(Main_element,[Element|Rest_of_set],Accumulated_list,Result) ->
    ?DBG("*Generating a subset for ~w ~n", [Main_element]),
    New_accumulated_list = lists:flatten([Element|Accumulated_list]),
    New_result = [New_accumulated_list|Result],
    ?DBG("Added ~w to the result: ~w ~n", [New_accumulated_list,New_result]),
    generate_subsets(Main_element,Rest_of_set,New_accumulated_list,New_result).
```

I am not sure if this snippet is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455632/split-an-erlang-list-x-into-a-list-of-all-xs-sublists (though not asking about parallelisation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pretty simple version which performs far better than version from rosettacode:

```
generate([]) -> [[]];
generate([H|T]) -> PT = generate(T),
  [ [H|X] || X <- PT ] ++ PT.
```

if you want even better performance you can try this:

```
generate([]) -> [[]];
generate([H|T]) -> PT = generate(T),
  generate(H, PT, PT).

generate(_, [], Acc) -> Acc;
generate(X, [H|T], Acc) -> generate(X, T, [[X|H]|Acc]).
```

But anyway I doubt if you will be able construct powerset of 30 elements set. According mine calculation it could consume more than 16GB. There can be some reusing of lists tails in mine second version but it would not help enough. I think you can even fail to bigger issue if you will implement it as parallel algorithm because there will be message copying.

Comment: Thanks! Will it become more memory efficient if I try to find only the subsets that have not less than N elements?

Comment: @MartinLee: Technically you don't have to precalculate anything. It depend what you would like do with result. Powerset is simply any number between 0 and 2^N-1 where N is number of set members and one in binary presentation denotes presence of corresponding member. You can do all calculation only with numbers and newer present subset per se.

Comment: I just wanted to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998363/generate-all-possible-subgraphs-of-a-directed-graph-keeping-the-number-of-vertic by generating a powerset. As I understand your last comment was about using bit counting to calculate a power set of a set. Could you please refer to any kind of implementation of power set bit counting technique in Erlang?

Comment: I have posted some advice [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998363/generate-all-possible-subgraphs-of-a-directed-graph-keeping-the-number-of-vertic/8016622#8016622)